# umask not being applied?

Tags: permissions, umask

I am setting the `umask` to a new value as below.
  However although I am applying `rxw` to the user, this does not seem to be respected (?)

```
/home/pkaramol
$ umask u=rxw,g=rw,o=r
/home/pkaramol
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rw,o=r
/home/pkaramol
$ rm -rf afile && touch afile;
/home/pkaramol
$ ls -l afile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pkaramol pkaramol 0 Μar   2 10:30 afile
```

**edit**:

```
$ mount | grep -E '\s/\s'
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)

$ mount | grep -i home
/home/pkaramol
```

Comment: @steve check my update;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`touch` creates files with permission 666 (-rw-rw-rw-) by default (with `umask 000`). `umask` can only subtract permissions ("take permissions away"). In your case only `o=w` is affected. It cannot add any flags (`u=x`) to newly created files. You have to use `chmod` for that.